# Calling a formula within a custom function using quosures

Tags: r, tidyverse

I am trying to run a t-test within a custom function, and am running into a quosure misapplication (I believe). Any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
library(tidyverse) 

tp_pull <- function(mydata, dv, iv){
  dv <- enquo(dv)
  iv <- enquo(iv)
  t.test(!!dv ~ !!iv, mydata) 
}

tp_pull(mydata = mtcars, dv = mpg, iv = vs)
```

My error message reads:

```
numerical expression has 2 elements: only the first usedNAs introduced by 
coercion
Show Traceback
Error in quo_name(dv):~!(!iv) : NA/NaN argument
```

For context this t-test will be part of a larger custom function.

Comment: Substituting args is normally done using `substitute`.  e.g.     `tp_pull <- function(mydata, dv, iv) t.test(formula(substitute(dv ~ iv)), mydata)`

Comment: @G.Grothendieck Your re-write was better than mine so I updated my answer. Hope that's OK.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Quosures are unique to tidyeval and are not supposed by the base R language. Right now they only work with dplyr. It is very unlikely these will ever work with base functions such as `t.test`.

If you want to do this with base R, you can use G. Grothendieck's suggestion of

```
tp_pull <- function(mydata, dv, iv){
  t.test(formula(substitute(dv ~ iv)), mydata)
}

tp_pull(mydata = mtcars, dv = mpg, iv = vs)
```

The substitute captures the un-evaulated symbol names from the promise passed to the call and allows you to re-assemble them into a new expression. The `formula()` call helps coerce the un-evaulated expression returned by `substitute()` into a proper R formula object.